# Memory allocation for value type and reference type in c#

Tags: c#, memory

based on the below code I was asked the question for memory management in case of value type and reference type in c#

```
public class X
{
    int i=0;
    string s= string.empty;
}

class test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        X obj = new X();  //creating instance of X class 
    }   
}
```

Based on the above code interviewer asked me when you create the instance of class X in class test then what will happen to the fields **[integer i and string s]** that are declared in 
class X in terms of memory, whether field integer **i** will be allocated to heap or stack.

Comment: http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not an object is allocated on the stack or the heap is an implementation detail, it's perfectly possible to create a completely valid implementation of C# that doesn't use stack-based allocation at all.

That said, it would be allocated on the heap, not the stack, for the .net framework, because it's a reference type: the object is created on the heap, the reference is likely held on the stack.

If it were a struct instead, then the struct layout would likely lie on the stack, but any reference types within would be references to objects on the heap. So, even if that were a struct, the string would live on the heap, while the integer would likely be on the stack.

Note: these are all implementation details, never treat them as set in stone: future implementations of .net, or alternate implementation of C# are free to change these details.